# Criteria API: can I access a given alias by its name

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, criteria-api

Is it possible with Criteria API to access a given alias via the Root object?

I have defined a Join and gave it the alias **"lead"**:

```
final Root<Project> project = cq.from(Project.class);
project.join(Project_.lead).alias("lead");
```

How can i gain access to that Join given just the Root and the alias (because Root is the only query handle, that I pass around)?

I've already tried to rebuild the Join by navigating again, but that seems to break the SQL statement:

```
    project.join(Project_.lead) // cannot do this
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From does have method [getJoins](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html#getJoins%28%29) and TupleElement method [getAlias](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TupleElement.html#getAlias%28%29). Root implements them, so following should work:

```
//TODO: apply generics; argument do not have to be root, but
//      something that implements From and TupleElement
private Join findJoin(Root root, String alias) {
    Set<Join> joins= root.getJoins();
    for (Join join: joins) {
        if (alias.equals(join.getAlias())) {
            return join;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No join for alias:" + alias);
}
```

Comment: thanks, i use the same approach, but it does not go deeper in the hierarchie - +1

Comment: getJoins only goes one level deep, so you're out of luck if you're joining on a join.